# Refit.ApiException Error Handling

Tags: refit

How do I get to the content of Refit.ApiException?

Depending on what the inner content is, I want to let the user know how to proceed. So I see that thrown exception has the following content ...

Content "{\"error\":\"invalid_grant\",\"error_description\":\"The user name or password is incorrect.\"}"

The question is, how do I access that?

Comment: Going through the RestService class https://github.com/paulcbetts/refit/blob/master/Refit/RestService.cs figured out I could use  the GetContentAs<T>  method  ((Refit.ApiException)ex).GetContentAs<Dictionary<String, String>>()

Answer (score 15):

You can add one catch block for ApiException. and you can get content from this catch block.
See below:

```
catch (ApiException ex)
{
    var content = ex.GetContentAs<Dictionary<String, String>>();
    Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}
```

Comment: After catching the exception and having the content, you need to go through the dictionary and get the message:
`var message = content.FirstOrDefault(pair => pair.Key == "ExceptionMessage").Value;`

Comment: var message = content.Result.FirstOrDefault(pair => pair.Key == "ExceptionMessage").Value;
Watch out for result if you haven't already fetched the Result from Task

Comment: Dictionary<string, string> doesn't always work.  I have a webapi throwing exception but the apiEx.GetContentAsAsync<Dictionary<string, string>>() throws exception of its own stating it can't parse the json.  If I use JsonObject instead of Dictionary, then I can see the exception from api is inside another Exception node and its Message key has the actual exception.  I don't have any confidence in the GetContentAsAsync<T>() method.  They should offered a non-generic method because the T is useless in some situations and unreliable to get the correct content.

Answer (score 10):

Going through the RestService class https://github.com/paulcbetts/refit/blob/master/Refit/RestService.cs

figured out I could use the GetContentAs method

So just did this..

```
((Refit.ApiException)ex).GetContentAs<Dictionary<String, String>>())
```

to parse out the key value content.

Answer (score 7):

As an extra heads-up:

`GetContentAs<T>();` is now deprecated.

Use `GetContentAsAsync<T>();` instead.

Answer (score 2):

With the latest version of API Exception, you can use the following code for getting the API content:

```
public static void HandleException( Exception exception )
{
    var content = ((Refit.ApiException)exception).GetContentAsAsync<Dictionary<string, string>>();
    var message = content.Result.FirstOrDefault( pair => pair.Key == "message" ).Value;
    Debug.WriteLine(message);           
}
```